How to bridge OpenTelemetry (opentelemetry-java-instrumentation) and Micrometer
My set-up:

Spring boot app based on version 3.1.3
Added dependency spring-boot-starter-actuator
Added custom metric MyHealthMetricsExportConfiguration according to the documentation (shown below)
Under /actuator/metrics I can see health metric
I've downloaded the latest otel java agent from github
I've added the config in intellij "vm options":


-javaagent:./opentelemetry-javaagent.jar 
-Dotel.metrics.exporter=otlp


I've run otel collector with receiver set to otlp

The question
I don't know how to make otel agent 'to see' and export spring metrics like f.e. 'MyHealthMetricsExportConfiguration'. On that blog it should be as simple as:
  // Unregister the OpenTelemetryMeterRegistry from Metrics.globalRegistry and make it available
  // as a Spring bean instead.
  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnClass(name = "io.opentelemetry.javaagent.OpenTelemetryAgent")
  public MeterRegistry otelRegistry() {
    Optional<MeterRegistry> otelRegistry = Metrics.globalRegistry.getRegistries().stream()
        .filter(r -> r.getClass().getName().contains("OpenTelemetryMeterRegistry"))
        .findAny();
    otelRegistry.ifPresent(Metrics.globalRegistry::remove);
    return otelRegistry.orElse(null);
  }

But that doesn't work for me. First of all durig bean creation Metrics.globalRegistry.getRegistries() is empty. Second of all, no health metric is available in otel collector. What can I do to make this agent send my custom metric to collector ?

@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class MyHealthMetricsExportConfiguration {

    public MyHealthMetricsExportConfiguration(MeterRegistry registry, HealthEndpoint healthEndpoint) {
        // This example presumes common tags (such as the app) are applied elsewhere
        Gauge.builder("health", healthEndpoint, this::getStatusCode).strongReference(true).register(registry);
    }

    private int getStatusCode(HealthEndpoint health) {
        Status status = health.health().getStatus();
        if (Status.UP.equals(status)) {
            return 3;
        }
        if (Status.OUT_OF_SERVICE.equals(status)) {
            return 2;
        }
        if (Status.DOWN.equals(status)) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

}


Idk exactly why it doesn't work as there's missing info about your initialization (autoconfigure, manual, envvars, version of agent,...) but as a hint, did you walk through https://opentelemetry.io/docs/languages/java/instrumentation/ ? If not, it should work, at least it did for me 2 days ago. Another place to ask might be #otel-java in cncf slack.

If you write an answer here, with f.e. a piece of code that works for you, I can give you a bounty then.

You need to enable OpenTelemetry bridge for Micrometer. It's disabled by default since version 2.0.0 of OpenTelemetry agent: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/releases/tag/v2.0.0
Agent Usage
For agent usage (your case), add this system property to your VM options: -Dotel.instrumentation.micrometer.enabled=true.
And I'd recommend setting the console exporter first (-Dotel.metrics.exporter=console), to verify just in console what gets exported regardless of what happens on the receiving side (on the collector).
P.S. You don't need the code piece from that blog post you mentioned (public MeterRegistry otelRegistry() {...). Maybe it is/was useful for something, but it's 2 years old and OpenTelemetry is still in alpha and has lots of breaking changes. So as of today, it worked without it for me. Note: the OpenTelemetryMeterRegistry that they mention there, is coming from the OpenTelemetry bridge lib (it's included in both agent and spring starter automatically).
OpenTelemetry Spring Starter Usage
For anybody using opentelemetry spring starter (io.opentelemetry.instrumentation:opentelemetry-spring-boot-starter) instead of the agent, the micrometer bridge is already included into it, so enable it by setting the same system property (for example, in application.properties, add line otel.instrumentation.micrometer.enabled=true).

I tried both options with the latest version (2.3.0), it worked (Spring Boot 3.2.5). Using your class, I got the following metric log (among many others) in the console output (see ...name=health...value=3.0...):
[otel.javaagent 2024-05-11 00:11:00:926 +0400] [PeriodicMetricReader-1] INFO io.opentelemetry.exporter.logging.LoggingMetricExporter - metric: ImmutableMetricData{resource=Resource{schemaUrl=https://opentelemetry.io/schemas/1.24.0, attributes={host.arch="amd64", host.name="DESKTOP-NCP", os.description="Windows 10 10.0", os.type="windows", process.command_line="C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.10.7-hotspot\bin\java.exe -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:13011,suspend=y,server=n -javaagent:./opentelemetry-javaagent.jar -Dotel.instrumentation.micrometer.enabled=true -Dotel.metrics.exporter=console -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true -Dmanagement.endpoints.jmx.exposure.include=* -javaagent:C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2024.1\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 com.backend.BackendApplication", process.executable.path="C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.10.7-hotspot\bin\java.exe", process.pid=44220, process.runtime.description="Eclipse Adoptium OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 17.0.10+7", process.runtime.name="OpenJDK Runtime Environment", process.runtime.version="17.0.10+7", service.instance.id="3c1b88b9-bdf6-457f-9e46-abb511930f80", service.name="backend", telemetry.distro.name="opentelemetry-java-instrumentation", telemetry.distro.version="2.3.0", telemetry.sdk.language="java", telemetry.sdk.name="opentelemetry", telemetry.sdk.version="1.37.0"}}, instrumentationScopeInfo=InstrumentationScopeInfo{name=io.opentelemetry.micrometer-1.5, version=null, schemaUrl=null, attributes={}}, name=health, description=, unit=, type=DOUBLE_GAUGE, data=ImmutableGaugeData{points=[ImmutableDoublePointData{startEpochNanos=1715371800406007400, epochNanos=1715371860420845000, attributes={}, value=3.0, exemplars=[]}]}}


Separately, Micrometer bridge is available on this page (find it in the table): https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/docs/supported-libraries.md#libraries--frameworks

Watch out: enabling Micrometer bridge will also start exporting its default Spring metrics and some have the same names as OpenTelemetry instrumentations. Because they have different attributes, the collector treats them as the same metric under different attributes, it seems. So in Grafana, for example, you'll see a single jvm_memory_used metric, but some dimensions will be duplicated (G1 Eden Space duplicate example):

...
comes from "io.opentelemetry.micrometer-1.5" bridge:
jvm_memory_used{area="heap", id="G1 Eden Space", instance="07d3f12f-c3a5-43bf-a268-bb80bceb6c56", job="stolpy-backend"}
...
comes from "io.opentelemetry.runtime-telemetry-java8":
jvm_memory_used{instance="07d3f12f-c3a5-43bf-a268-bb80bceb6c56", job="stolpy-backend", jvm_memory_pool_name="G1 Eden Space", jvm_memory_type="heap"}


So you probably want to disable default Spring Micrometer metrics, it should be explained somewhere in the docs how to do that. This SO post for example mentions something: Spring Boot Actuator/Micrometer Metrics Disable Some

How did you know it? should I debug low level stuff after working hours to be better, go through SO qeustions/answers to be familiar with problems like these?
Downvote me as much as you want all, but I'm impressed and I would appreciate a suggestion what to do to be like you

@user3529850 Ironically, I stumbled upon your question yesterday, while actually trying to find an answer for my own OpenTelemetry question (not on SO), and noticed that this one I can answer :) I'm still learning OpenTelemetry myself. I had to experiment a lot (checking debug output is often a good idea), read a lot of their docs, blogs, Github code, release notes etc to understand what's going on. Unfortunately, the information is very poor so far I agree, hope they improve after alpha version. Randomly out of my experiments I knew the answer to your question.

THANK YOU so much -> was not easy finding this, but here the docs: https://opentelemetry.io/docs/zero-code/java/spring-boot-starter/out-of-the-box-instrumentation/

From your description it seems that you mix 2 approaches

using opentelemetry-spring-boot-starter which means the optl agent is contained within your spring-boot jar
using -javaagent: which will instrument your spring-boot app on runtime

this condition @ConditionalOnClass(name = "io.opentelemetry.javaagent.OpenTelemetryAgent") will return false for the second option (put a breakpoint or debug log in that been and you'll see your app does not create otelRegistry  bean).
If you choose to go with javaagent + prometheus (include io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus in your dependencies) you can give up OpenTelemetryMeterRegistry (the conditional bean)
Metrics.globalRegistry.getRegistries() to return PrometheusMeterRegistry
If you prefer the optl format you should follow the above link
